# How to display non-ASCII characters from a XML output

Tags: html, xml, unicode

I get this output in a XML element:

```
&#xA3;111.00
```

It should be `£111.00`.

How can i sort this out so that all unicode characters are displayed rather than the code. I am using linux tool wget to fetch the xml file from the Internet. Perhaps some sort of convertor?

I am viewing the file in putty  , i am parsing the file and i want to clean the input before parsing.

I am using xml_grep2 to get the elements i want and then cat filename | while read .....

Comment: Where are you trying to display this?

Comment: where and how are you displaying things? It is perfectly correct for the XML to have the &#xA3; in it so the problem is with whatever you are using to display that so you need to explain what that is...

Comment: What, precisely, does the XML look like? What does the output look like? Where are you displaying the output? How are you getting the data from the XML to the output?

Comment: i now get  Â character after processing with xml_grep2 so i now get  Â£111

Comment: What is your target encoding? UTF-8?

Comment: You have a Useless Use of Cat there, BTW.

Comment: "I am using xml_grep2 to get the elements i want and then cat filename | while read" — please show us your actual code and not a rough description of it.

Comment: why is it useless? though efficiency is not really an issue as it's a simple script

Comment: wget $url
xml_grep2 '//scores' index* > results

cat results | while read LINE
do

Comment: looks like an issue with xml_grep2 , it is outputting the unicode characters but also has a  Â in front of each unicode character

Comment: I'd say if you don't have a Unicode-clean terminal/processing pipeline then leave the character references alone. The tool you're sending the data to should be parsing the XML using a proper XML parser **and not any kind of regex-based bodge, ever**; an XML parser doesn't care whether its input is raw characters or character references.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML::Entities to replace the entities with literal character codes. I don't know how good its coverage is, though. There are bound to be similar tools for other languages if you are not comfortable with Perl. [http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aEntities)

```
sh$ echo '&#xA3;111.00' | perl -CSD -MHTML::Entities -pe 'decode_entities($_)'
£111.00
```

This won't work if the HTML::Entities module is not installed. If you need to install it, there are numerous tutorials about the CPAN on the Internet.

**Edit**: Add usage example.  The `-CSD` option might not be necessary on your system, but on OSX at least, I got garbage output without it.

Comment: However this would risk breaking well-formedness if there's a `&lt;`, `&amp;` etc entity reference in it.

Comment: I'm guessing that is not an issue here, but as the OP is not answering any requests for clarification, I am indeed purely guessing. @bobince: either way, a good point to bring up.

Comment: I'm not having an issue with HTML entities at all. I am fetching a XML file which xml_grep2 parses but screws up.

Comment: The "code" you are complaining about in the question is known as "entities".  It is how HTML, and XML, and SGML, encode characters which are reserved for markup (i.e. `<>&`) or nonportable in their native representation. Granted, the module name HTML::Entities is slightly misleading, as it's not just useful for HTML.

Comment: ok thanks, however i'm now past the stage of entities. i just need to remove  Ã before every pound. tr -d does it but when i save the output of tr -d the  Ã appears once more.

Comment: Sounds like a locale problem.  Maybe if you replied to the clarifying questions people have posted, somebody would be inclined to continue to look at this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i'm going to close this question now.

After parsing the file with xml_grep2 i was able to get a clean output however was seeing this  Ã character in the file. I changed putty settings for character set to UTF-8 from ISO-8859 to resolve that.